# Php upload script on raspberry pi

Tags: php, apache2, raspberry-pi2

I have set up a apache2 webserver on my raspberry pi (jessie). I have a file upload php script in my `/var/www/html/` folder. This script is supposed to upload the file to a `/uploads` folder (`/var/www/html/uploads`). The script is:

```
$folder = "/uploads";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filep"]["tmp_name"] , "$folder".$_FILES["filep"]["name"]);
```

When I try to upload a file, I get upload success message and the name of file gets updated to the database, but when I check the `/uploads` folder, I don't see the file. I have given `chmod 777 permission` to the folder and changed `upload_max_filesize` to `16M` and `post_max_size` to `32M`. None of the methods worked.

Is my path wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Nirup. Welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, please put your code inside code blocks and indent it to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder `/uploads` is in your file system root and not under `/var/www/html`. To use a folder relative to the current directory leave out the leading `/` or use the constant [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) to get the current directory.

```
$folder = "uploads/"; 
// or
$folder = __DIR__."/uploads/";
```

You could also use the complete path to the folder:

```
$folder = "/var/www/html/uploads/";
```

Comment: Oh, that was a dumb question! :) its working when I edited it as "/var/www/html/uploads/".. Thank you!